# can't seem to publish my updated pgp key for Travis-CI to pick it up

Tags: travis-ci, gnupg, maven-gpg-plugin

I've made some releases to Maven central for my project over the years, using Travis-CI. The last release was 2 months ago, and I proceeded as I usually did.

But today, for some reason, I am getting this error, while I didn't change anything in my setup :

```
"gpg: no default secret key: unusable secret key"
```

After some research, I realized my key had expired.. so I found few resources that explained how to update the expiry date. I followed and pushed the date by 2 years, and now on my machine, I have this when I list the keys, so it looks OK :

[image]

Then, I publish the key and don't get any error message (so I assume it goes well) :

[image]

Finally, I trigger my failing travis-ci build again, but I keep having the same error.

I added a few commands before the actual deployment to get more information - indeed, my key is still seen as expired :

[image]

What else can I try to check my updated key is properly published, and that Travis-ci gets it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that helped me investigate : we can check our key on the server through a basic web interface, on http://pool.sks-keyservers.net - it confirmed my key was not updated there.

I tried few more commands to send my key based on what I could find here and there :

- gpg -v --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --send-key *MY_KEY*
- gpg -v --keyserver hkp://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net --send-key *MY_KEY*
- gpg -v --keyserver hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net --send-key *MY_KEY*

One of them must have made a difference, because I now see an updated expiry date, even though the original one is still there.

Finally, I updated my travis-ci file to run these 2 commands :

```
gpg -v --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --refresh-keys
gpg -v --list-keys
```

and I got the confirmation my keys were updated before signing the artifacts